# Positon a div over table

Tags: html, css

I have a table what can contain divs. Table row height is 100px and divs can be up to 200px. If the div is higher than table row i need it to overlay the table and also cover the bottom row. I managed to do this with absolute position like this:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
 <table>
  <tr height="100">
    <td>
      <div style="position: absolute; height: 200px">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="100">
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  ... (many more rows)
 </table>
</div>
```

This way everything is good. 
The problem is that when table becomes very long and it makes a scroll (because of the main divs overflow: auto) and i start to scroll the divs stay in their position and only the table moves. Also the bottom divs are shown through the background. I tried changing the position of the divs to relative but that way the divs dont overlay the table anymore but push the table row to 200 pixels.

How can this be solved? 
Thank you! :)

Comment: Please post a complete code example (i.e. CSS too) and a jsFiddle if possible.

Comment: Where is your DIV tag closed?

Comment: The unclosed DIV in your TD is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...or handle the mechanics directly on your div elements by having 2 of them, rather than trying to get table elements to play nice with your HTML structuring.  Tables are great for one purpose, managing tabular data. They are not great for branding your data.  The following will be easier for you maintain and update!

```
  <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="position:relative; height:200px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; height: 200px"></div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Then upgrade this even further by keeping all your styles inside the style sheet and simply calling your classes...

```
   <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="sub-wrapper">
            <div class="sub-content">
              </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="sub-wrapper">
            <div class="sub-content">
              </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
     ...etc...
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the table cells `position:relative` and may want to add the top and left position of the div

**Edit**

just found out tds have a problem with relative positioning so you are better making a relative div and then putting your absolute div within this:

```
<table>
  <tr height="100">
    <td>
      <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; height: 200px"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EgBAy/